# GMS2, when destroying a child, all children get affected. Parent object not functioning as intended

Tags: game-maker-studio-2

I am having an issue with my parent object and its children.
My intention is to have an enemy spawner (child) that functions independently of other children spawners . The spawner will spawn enemies until the desired amount is reached and then be destroyed (child is destroyed). However, when I destroy an enemy spawned by my parent spawner object, all children spawners spawn an enemy instead. Example. I have two children spawnwers that spawn an enemy. When I destroy from child A, child A and B both spawn an enemy. Furthermore, when I destroy the required amount of enemies from the spawner, both A and B child spawners are destroyed except for just A child.

Below is code.

///PARENT SPAWNER OBJECT

```
PARENT STEP EVENT
if(enemy_dead_count <= 0){
sprite_index = sDestroyed_Ghost_Spawner;
if (sprite_index == sDestroyed_Ghost_Spawner){
    if(image_index >= 9 && image_index < 10){
        image_index = 9;
    }
}

} else {
    while(spawn_ghost == 0){
        instance_create_layer(x,y+32,"Player",oEnemy_spawner_animation);
        spawn_ghost += 1;
    }
}

//PARENT CREATE EVENT
    spawn_ghost = 0;
    enemy_dead_count = 3;
```

The object, oEnemy_spawner_animation, is an object that scales its xscale and yscale and when reaches a desired size changes the instance to oEnemy_ghost

//ANIMATION CODE BELOW

```
//animator create event
image_xscale = 0;
image_yscale = 0;


//animator step event
if image_xscale <= 1 {
image_xscale += 0.008;
image_yscale = image_xscale;
} else{
    image_xscale = 1;
    //update yscale
    image_yscale = image_xscale;
    instance_change(oEnemy_ghost,true);
}
```

In the Enemy Parent , I wont post all the code as it is quite extensive but ill post the relevant

```
if(hp<=0){
instance_destroy();


with(x,y,oEnemy_ghost_spawner){
    
    spawn_ghost = 0;
    enemy_dead_count -= 1;
}
```

}

Above, when an enemy is destroyed, I use the with statement to spawn a new enemy.
I am targeting the child here instead of the parent , perhaps that's the problem?

I have a feeling I need to somehow tie the enemy spawned ID to the child spawner ID, but I do not know how to achieve this.

Any thoughts on how to achieve my intended functionality? How do I make my children spawners function independently of eachother?

Answer (score 0):

With the `with()` function, you'll go through every object of that type. I think if that includes a parent, it'll affect the children as well.

A possible solution could be to:

- Make another child of the current 'parent' function, and use the current parent as just a base of the enemy spawner that'll affect all enemy spawners, and not an entity of itself.
- make a boolean that'll only be set to true for the parent (like `isParent`), and set it to false for it's children.
- if you want to make each spawner unique of each other, then you could try giving them an unique ID, and inside the `with()` function, search for that unique ID if it's the one you're looking for.